# Configuration File for Java Application to change path

Tags: java

I have made a Java (.jar) application that uses and external image and MS Access database.

Both things are accessed using a path. This won't work if I give the application to my friend to test as the path wont match.

I was wondering if I could make configuration settings file that would change the path by editing the settings file and make the application work fine instead of opening the source code in editor and editing there.

Comment: Sure, why couldn't you?

Comment: I need to know how to do it

Comment: Doesn't google work today?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by creating a configuration file. Lets say your configuration file is "config.properties". You can mention properties required in file like

```
#comment
imageFile=C://imagePath
database=<path to db>
username=
password=
```

Then read the file

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream in = null;

in= new FileInputStream("config.properties");
//load a properties file
properties.load(input);

// get the property value and print it out
System.out.println(properties.getProperty("imageFile"));
---
```

Make sure file is accessible by keeping it in classpath.

Comment: what do you mean by keeping the file in classpath? Does it mean that I have to place the file where class files of my projects are??? If that is what you mean how is 3rd party user going to edit it if I only give the jar redistributable?

Comment: there are multiple ways you can keep config file accessible. Since I did not mention full path of the file, I said keep it as source/in classpath etc. If you give absolute path, keep it any location accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Properties properties;    
    try(InputStream input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("app.properties")) {
       properties = new Properties();
       properties.load(input);
  } catch (IOException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
  System.out.println(properties.getProperty("my.path"));
```

Property file format is very simple

```
my.path = /home/file.txt
semicolon_Also_delimiter:value
semicolon\:can\:be\:escaped:value
```